# AJAX call using admin-ajax URL is returning 400 bad request

Tags: ajax

I am attempting to create an AJAX call to pass custom taxonomy into my `WP_Query` but I am getting `400 (Bad Request)`. I believe my `data` array is built correctly so I am not sure what's causing it. Does anything look off here? Is there a way for me to get a more detailed error of why it is returning error 400?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:ajaxUrl,
    data: {
        taxonomy: 'products',
        slug: 'shirts'
    },
    beforeSend:function(xhr){

    },
    success:function(data){
      $('#response').html(data); // insert data
    }
});
```

I console logged `ajaxUrl` and I am getting the correct path to `admin-ajax.php` so I know that's not the issue. I think it has to have something to do with `data`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot the "action" key in your data array. With that key you define which function is called from your plugin or function.php File. [For more information see the Wordpress documentation - AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side)

Comment: Knew it was something simple, thank you! Working great now.